# Hibernate mapping of internationalized database

Tags: java, internationalization, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I want to get international content from database based on locale provided in hibernate query. This is a question about hibernate mapping but please feel free to propose better database design if mine is wrong.

My DB design (simplified):
[db design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4L5m.jpg)
So I have table with non translatable data and additional table with translated content but with additional field "locale" for distinction of language.

My **java classes** looks like this:

```
public class Car {

private Long id;
private Long length;
private Long weight;
private CarTranslated carTranslated;

// getters and setters

public class CarTranslated {

private Long id;
private Long carId;
private String desc;

// getters and setters
```

I want to be able to get one car with single query. With regular jdbc I would use something like this **sql query**:

```
public Car getById(Long id, Locale locale) {
Car c = new Car();
String sql = "select c.car_id, c.length, c.weight, ct.id, ct.descryption, 
ct.car_id as "Translated car_id" from car c join car_translated ct on
(c.car_id =   ct.car_id) where c.car_id ="+ id+" and ct.locale ='"+locale+"'";

// code to set fields of the object using ResultSet

return c;
}
```

What would be a hibernate annotation mapping and query for this setup? I tried several attempts but to no avail. Currently my best attempt was as below:

**Mapping:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAR")
public class Car {

@Id
@Column(name="car_id")
private Long carId;

@Column (name="weight")
private Long carWeight;

@Column (name="length")
private Long carLength;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name ="CAR_ID")
private CarTranslated localized;

// getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name="CAR_TRANSLATED")
public class CarTranslated {

@Id
@Column (name="id")
private Long id;

@Column (name="car_id")
private Long carId;

@Column (name="descryption")
private String desc;

@Column(name="locale")
private Locale locale;
```

**DAO:**

```
public Car getCarById(Locale locale, Long id) {
    Car car = new Car();
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Car.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("carId", id));
        Criteria cr1 = session.createCriteria(CarTranslated.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("locale", locale));

        car = (Car) cr.uniqueResult();
        car.setLocalized((CarTranslated) cr1.uniqueResult());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return car;
}
```

This is a work-around and I'm wondering what would be a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an annotation on both columns when mapping to a FK. ([JavaDoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html))